# tkinter not showing initial table created on canvas

Tags: python-3.x, tkinter

The following code is a snippet of a table initially constructed with x cols and y rows; I have omitted the code relating to addition or removal of cols or rows. (the onFrameConfigure and onCanvasConfigure functions were copied from an answer on Jan 8 '16, published by @RDT2).
My problem: the initial table is properly created. But if I ask for 15 columns and 10 rows, the root window only shows the first 7 columns and the first 11 rows, thus forcing the scroll even though there is plently of space for the remaining rows and columns. Since, to the best of my knowledge, I am not placing any constraints anywhere, I am at a loss to explain and correct this behaviour.

```
#!/usr/bin/env python3
from tkinter import *
class Calc_Table(Frame):
    def __init__(self, root, cols, rows):
        Frame.__init__(self, root)
        self.cols = cols
        self.rows = rows
        self.configure(bg='green')
        self.grid(sticky=NSEW)
        self.grid_columnconfigure(0, weight=1)
        self.grid_rowconfigure(0, weight=1) 
        self.hsb = Scrollbar(orient=HORIZONTAL)
        self.hsb.grid(row = 1, column = 0, sticky = EW)
        self.vsb = Scrollbar(orient=VERTICAL)
        self.vsb.grid(row = 0, column = 1, sticky = NS)
        self.canvas = Canvas(self, xscrollcommand = self.hsb.set, yscrollcommand = self.vsb.set, bg='yellow')
        self.canvas.grid(row = 0, column = 0, sticky = NSEW)
        self.canvas.grid_rowconfigure(0, weight = 1)
        self.canvas.grid_columnconfigure(0, weight = 1)
        self.canvas.bind("<Configure>", self.onCanvasConfigure)
        self.hsb.config(command = self.canvas.xview)
        self.vsb.config(command = self.canvas.yview)
        self.table_frame = self.create_table(self.cols,self.rows)         
        self.table_frame.bind("<Configure>", self.onFrameConfigure)
        self.window = self.canvas.create_window((0, 0), window = self.table_frame, anchor=NW)
        self.canvas.config(scrollregion = self.canvas.bbox('all'))

    def onFrameConfigure(self, event):
        self.canvas.update_idletasks()
        self.canvas.configure(scrollregion=self.canvas.bbox('all'))

    def onCanvasConfigure(self, event):
        minWidth = self.table_frame.winfo_reqwidth()
        minHeight = self.table_frame.winfo_reqheight()
        if self.canvas.winfo_width() >= minWidth:
            newWidth = self.winfo_width()
            self.hsb.grid_remove()
        else:
            newWidth = minWidth
            self.hsb.grid()
        if self.canvas.winfo_height() >= minHeight:
            newHeight = self.winfo_height()
            self.vsb.grid_remove()
        else:
            newHeight = minHeight
            self.vsb.grid()
        self.canvas.itemconfig(self.window, width=newWidth, height=newHeight)

    def create_table(self, cols, rows):          # create initial table
        self.table_frame = Frame(self.canvas)
        self.table_frame.grid(column = 0, row = 0, sticky = NSEW)
        self.cols, self.rows = cols, rows
        for c in range(self.cols):
            for r in range(self.rows):
                if c == 0 and r == 0:
                    self.lbl = Label(self.table_frame, width=6, height=1, bg="white",
                                     text="? ? ?", relief=RAISED)
                    self.lbl.grid(column=c, row=r, padx=1, pady=1, sticky=NSEW)
                elif c == 0 and r != 0:
                    self.lbl = Label(self.table_frame, width=6, height=1, bg="white", 
                                     text=f"R{r}",relief=RAISED)
                    self.lbl.grid(column=c, row=r, padx=1, pady=1, sticky=NSEW)
                elif c != 0 and r == 0:
                    self.lbl = Label(self.table_frame, width=6, height=1, bg="white",
                                     text=f"C{c}",relief=RAISED)
                    self.lbl.grid(column=c, row=r, padx=1, pady=1, sticky=NSEW)
                else:
                    self.txt =Text(self.table_frame, width=6, height=1, bg="white",
                                   relief=SUNKEN)
                    self.txt.grid(column=c, row=r, padx=1, pady=1, sticky=NSEW)
        for c in range(self.cols):
            self.table_frame.grid_columnconfigure(c, weight=1)
        for r in range(self.rows):
            self.table_frame.grid_rowconfigure(r, weight=1
        for slave in self.table_frame.grid_slaves():
            slave.bind("<Button-1>", self.cmd)
        return self.table_frame              
    def cmd(self, event):
        print(event.widget.grid_info())

if __name__ == '__main__': 
    cols = int(input("How many columns? "))
    assert isinstance(int(cols), int), "integers only, please"
    rows = int(input("How many rows? "))
    assert isinstance(int(rows), int), "integers only, please"
    root = Tk()
    root.geometry("+10+10")
    root.title("Master Table")
    root.grid_columnconfigure(0, weight=1)
    root.grid_rowconfigure(0, weight=1)
    my_table = Calc_Table(root, cols, rows)
    root.mainloop()
```

Comment: Your code has a number of syntax errors and the create_table method is never called so a table is never created.

Comment: I have updated the code to include two lines inadvertently missing.

Comment: You call `self.create_table` before you create `self.canvas`. That doesn't work because the `self.create_table` method uses the canvas object to create a Frame in. If you move the `self.create_table` call to after the creation of the Canvas the code seems to work as intended.

Comment: @fhdrsdg : I am sorry that my cut and paste let me down again, because what you suggested was how I have had it in my file. In addition, I have changed the wording at the beginning of the question, to make the nature of the problem clearer for everybody. Thks for your help.

Answer (score 1):

The "problem" is that you never specify the canvas size. Therefore, it will be the default size, no matter the contents.

To specify the size however, you need to know the size of the created Frame. You can set the size of the Canvas with `self.canvas.config()` and get the requested size of the Frame with `self.table_frame.winfo_reqwidth()` and `self.table_frame.winfo_reqheight()`, but only after the Frame has been drawn. You can delay an action until all else is done with `after_idle`. Because `after_idle` expects a function reference and not a function call, wrap the call to `self.canvas.config()` in a `lambda`.

Bringing this all together, you can use

```
root.after_idle(lambda: self.canvas.config(width=self.table_frame.winfo_reqwidth(), height=self.table_frame.winfo_reqheight()))
```

at the end of your `__init__` function to resize the Canvas to whatever size the Frame needs. You could even throw in something like `min(self.table_frame.winfo_reqwidth(), 800)` to have a maximum initial size.

Comment: I inserted the self.canvas.config(width= ...., height=...) command as the very last command on the the onCanvasConfigure function, and it worked perfectly. Then I commented it out and inserted it into the onFrameConfigure function, and again it worked fine. Q1: what 'event' triggered the command, since I did not touch the keyboard after inputing cols and rows required. Q2: are any of these workarounds failsafe or the root.after_idle command is a must, in your estimation? Anyway, thks a ton.

Comment: Ah yeah you are right. Things like getting the height and width of widgets usually only work after waiting for the geometry manager to draw the widgets. However, since `reqwidth` doesn't give the actual size but a calculated size based on its contents, you don't actually need to wait for the geometry manager. You can get the `reqwidth` as soon as you have added all widgets.

Comment: yes, but (1) self.canvas.config(.....) only works  if placed in onFrameConfigure or onCanvasConfigure, ie. the event driven functions. (2) if placed at the end of __init__ , nothing is displayed except the scrollbars; I really cannot think of an acceptable explanation for this.

Comment: Okay so my last comment was incorrect. The widget does need to be drawn before `reqwidth` and `reqheight` return the correct numbers. Therefore, when you put the `canvas.config` in `__init__` you do need the `after_idle`. The reason it works without `after_idle` in  `onFrameConfigure` and `onCanvasConfigure` is because these functions are called based on events, which are only captured after the mainloop has started. However, the command I wrote is only meant to set the initial size of the canvas, so putting in in the event-driven functions seems off to me, I'd stay with the line in my answer.